# Quickly resubmitting ASP MVC Ajax Form causes hang up in javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm using ASP MVC 2 and JQuery. I have a search mask that consists of the HTML Helper Ajax.BeginForm. It basically looks like this:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", new AjaxOptions{... LoadingElementId = "LoadingElement", OnComplete = "HideLoadingAnimation"...}
```

The div element with ID "LoadingElement" simply contains an animated gif image. In its CSS definition it has the following values:

```
#LoadingAnimationWindow{ position: fixed; border-width: 10px; display:none; z-index: 9999;}
```

I also created a nice Animation Mask that creates a transparent but colored overlay over the page while the loading animation is being displayed. Its CSS definition is as follows:

```
#LoadingAnimationMask{ position:absolute; z-index: 9000; display:none;}
```

The HideLoadingAnimation() function looks like this:

```
function HideLoadingAnimation() {$('#LoadingAnimationMask, #LoadingAnimationWindow').hide();}
```

Now when I search, my Ajax.BeginForm from above gets submitted. This all works perfectly fine. The loading animation etc are all displayed. However, when I submit the form quickly maybe 3 or 4 times in a row, my loading animation won't disappear. It just hangs there and doesn't go away. This only happens if I resubmit the form quickly. I know this might be the kind of bug that you could live with but I still would like to fix it. Does anyone know of a solution or has anyone experienced the same issues? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you sure there are no JS errors when that behaviour happens?

Comment: I'll check and get back to you. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I checked and both the IE9 developer tools (the site only has to work with IE 8/9) and Visual Studio aren't showing any JS errors. Do you recommend checking it with Firefox's firebug or should the IE9 dev tools catch the JS error if it occurred?

Comment: Yes, FireBug or Chromes dev tools are greater than ie dev tools in almost all ways. Even though the site doesn't need to run these browsers the dev tools are quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

After the first form submit, have you considered disabling the submit button until after the results have loaded?

Comment: That's a good idea. I think I'll try that thanks :). Just curious though: have you had or heard of problems like this before?

Comment: Not specifically, however I would assume that a weird javascript / malformed html or even a timing issue is what is giving you headaches.